# Setting the x86 debug registers during handling of an exception

Tags: c, debugging, exception

I am able to set up a HW breakpoint (writing or reading of an address) without problems and it also works.
If I try to do the same from a Vectored Exception handler the registers are set (confirmed it with set/getThreadContext), but the same SW never breaks.
The address and the setup functions are the same, the only difference that I see is that, if I set the breakpoint from the main code, it works; if I do the same from a vectored exception handler (during where an unrelated exception has happened) the breakpoint will not have any effect.

The code that should break on the breakpoint is of course outside of the exception handler.
I can't find any relevant information in the IA32 Software Manual.

Perhaps some of you had this problem. Any help is appreciated.

Edit:
Here is a very crude example, don't mind the warnings. If compiled with #define DIRECT, the program terminates because of the uncaught SINGLE_STEP, if compiled without nothing happens.
To be clear, this is just an ugly, messy, quick example.

```
// The following macros define the minimum required platform.  The minimum required platform
// is the earliest version of Windows, Internet Explorer etc. that has the necessary features to run
// your application.  The macros work by enabling all features available on platform versions up to and
// including the version specified.

// Modify the following defines if you have to target a platform prior to the ones specified below.
// Refer to MSDN for the latest info on corresponding values for different platforms.
#ifndef WINVER                          // Specifies that the minimum required platform is Windows Vista.
#define WINVER 0x0600           // Change this to the appropriate value to target other versions of Windows.
#endif

#ifndef _WIN32_WINNT            // Specifies that the minimum required platform is Windows Vista.
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0600     // Change this to the appropriate value to target other versions of Windows.
#endif

#ifndef _WIN32_WINDOWS          // Specifies that the minimum required platform is Windows 98.
#define _WIN32_WINDOWS 0x0410 // Change this to the appropriate value to target Windows Me or later.
#endif

#ifndef _WIN32_IE                       // Specifies that the minimum required platform is Internet Explorer 7.0.
#define _WIN32_IE 0x0700        // Change this to the appropriate value to target other versions of IE.
#endif

#include "windows.h"
#include "stdio.h"

#define DR7_CONFIG(num, lg, rw, size)   ((((rw & 3) << (16 + 4 * num)) | ((size & 3) << (18 + 4 * num))) | (lg << (2 * num)))
HANDLE mainThread;

//#define DIRECT

DWORD WINAPI LibAsilEmu_ArrayBoundsMonitor(LPVOID lpParameter)
{
    MSG msg;
    CONTEXT tcontext;
    HANDLE th;
    DWORD temp = 0;
    IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER *psec;


    th = OpenThread(THREAD_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, mainThread);

                temp = SuspendThread(th);
                tcontext.ContextFlags = CONTEXT_DEBUG_REGISTERS;
                temp = GetThreadContext(th, &tcontext);
                tcontext.Dr6 = 0;
                tcontext.Dr0 = lpParameter;
                tcontext.Dr2 = lpParameter;
                tcontext.Dr3 = lpParameter;
                tcontext.Dr1 = lpParameter;
                tcontext.Dr7 = 0xffffffff;//DR7_CONFIG(0, 1, 2, 3) | DR7_CONFIG(1, 1, 2, 3) | 256;
                temp = SetThreadContext(th, &tcontext);
                temp = GetThreadContext(th, &tcontext);
                temp = ResumeThread(th);
    return 0;
}
HANDLE child;


unsigned int test_array[10];


LONG WINAPI LibAsilEmu_TopLevelVectoredFilter(struct _EXCEPTION_POINTERS *ExceptionInfo)
{
    child = CreateThread(NULL, 0x4000, LibAsilEmu_ArrayBoundsMonitor, &test_array[2], 0, NULL);
    while (WAIT_OBJECT_0 != WaitForSingleObject(child, 0));
    return EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION;
}

int main(void)
{
    int i;

    printf("%p\n", test_array); fflush(stdout);
    printf("sizeof %d\n", sizeof(test_array));

    mainThread = GetCurrentThreadId();

#ifdef DIRECT
    child = CreateThread(NULL, 0x4000, LibAsilEmu_ArrayBoundsMonitor, &test_array[2], 0, NULL);
    // Edit 2: the wait was missing
    while (WAIT_OBJECT_0 != WaitForSingleObject(child, 0));
#else
    AddVectoredExceptionHandler(1, &LibAsilEmu_TopLevelVectoredFilter);
    RaiseException(0,0,0,0);
#endif


    printf("thread ready\n");

    printf("ta %p\n", &(test_array[10]));
    for (i = 0; i < 15; ++i)
    {
        *((char*)test_array) += 0x25;
        test_array[i] += 0x15151515;
        printf("%2d %d %p\n", i, test_array[i], &(test_array[i])); fflush(stdout);
    }
    printf("ta %d\n", test_array[10]);
    printf("exit\n\nexit\n\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not know the specifics of your problem because there is no code provided in your description.  i.e., it could simply be a coding error.  So, with no other information all that I can think is to point you to a link with some example code on using vectored exception handling   ***[HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681411%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)***  Hope this helps, otherwise, post some code

[EDIT 1]

First, I would guess you are not the first to see this problem, Vectored exception handling has been around since XP.  Others most certainly have seen it.

Probably no need to say it (but I will anyway) debuggers, when running multiple threads behave differently than they do in 
in single thread.  You are calling your vectored exception handler from a separate thread.  It seems likely  this is somehow related to the fact you cannot see the breakpoint when running from thread.  Do you have the abilty to point your debugger to a specific thread? ***[See Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff539042%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)***

I have one other suggestion - Since the real point of this question is to determine why your HW break point is not being set when attempted using a Vectored Exception Handler, consider changing the title of this post to something like:
***Cannot set HW breakpoints using Vectored Exception handler.***
it may get more attention.  (I would have done this myself, but did not want to make the presumption you would be okay with that :)

***[EDIT 2]***

I see in your example that in `main()`, you are calling `AddVectoredExceptionHandler()` from within a new thread.  But the function

```
LONG WINAPI LibAsilEmu_TopLevelVectoredFilter(struct _EXCEPTION_POINTERS *ExceptionInfo)
{
    child = CreateThread(NULL, 0x4000, LibAsilEmu_ArrayBoundsMonitor, &test_array[2], 0, NULL);
    while (WAIT_OBJECT_0 != WaitForSingleObject(child, 0));
    return EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION;
}
```

creates yet another new thread, where  `LibAsilEmu_ArrayBoundsMonitor` in turn opens the main thread again.  This seems an odd series of events to me.  Is this code something you have seen used somewhere else, and used in conjunction with *vectored exception handling*?

Comment: My Exception handler is pretty huge and it works also. At this point I'm wondering whether someone had this problem before. Can it be that debugging registers can't be set in the middle of an "active" exception? Pasting here everything is almost pointless.

Comment: I have provided an example if that helps.

Comment: The drX registers are set from a thread, because the only way to set these "protected" registers in user mode is through SetThreadContext (to write them directly one would need ring 0 or real mode). The break point needs to be acted on from the main thread (read int main()). To illustrate that there is (at least for now) an undocumented behaviour, depending on the definition DEFINE I either create the thread (the one that actually writes the Dr registers) from main or from the Exception Handler. When created from main, the setup works, when created from the exception handler it does not.

Comment: There are newer more than two threads, 1. the main thread were "int main" is executing, and, let's call it the debug thread, which sets the registers. The debug thread is either launched directly from main, or from the exception handler, which itself runs in the context of the main thread.

Comment: If you have the time and mingw at hand, could you compile and run the code once with "#define DIRECT" and once without. In my case the one without the DIRECT (where the debug thread is launched from main) behaves as it should.

Comment: By the way "I see in your example that in main(), you are calling AddVectoredExceptionHandler() from within a new thread.", the exception handler is registered from main() and not from another thread.